# dynamically loading data from JSON in Google App Script on Sites

Tags: json, google-apps-script, jquery-masonry, google-sites

I have a google app script where I am trying to get data from a JSON call:

```
 var ajaxError = function(){
  $loadingItem.text('Could not load examples :(');
};

// dynamically load sites using Masonry from Zootool
$.getJSON('http://zootool.com/api/users/items/?username=desandro' +
    '&apikey=8b604e5d4841c2cd976241dd90d319d7' +
    '&tag=bestofmasonry&callback=?')
  .error( ajaxError() )
  .success(function( data ){...
```

Basically I am trying to implement this JQuery plugin example http://masonry.desandro.com/
in a Google Apps script returning Html from a file.

This Jason call ends up in error... but why? where can I see what is going wrong? Javascript console is not displaying any error. The URL works: http://zootool.com/api/users/items/?username=desandro&apikey=8b604e5d4841c2cd976241dd90d319d7&tag=bestofmasonry&callback=?

Comment: Add parameters to the error function so that you can better debug the issue. They would look like this `function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. Then you can just `console.log` the latter two.

Comment: How would I pass the values?
`var ajaxError = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      $loadingItem.text('Could not load examples :(');
      console.log(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
    };
    
    // dynamically load sites using Masonry from Zootool
    $.getJSON('http://zootool.com/api/users/items/?username=desandro' +
        '&apikey=8b604e5d4841c2cd976241dd90d319d7' +
        '&tag=bestofmasonry&callback=?')
      .error( ajaxError() )
      .success(function( data ){}`
Unsure how I add them in the **`.error(ajaxError(???))`**

Comment: printing the jqXHR won't get you too much info, just print the textStatus and the errorThrown for now. Then you can call `.error(ajaxError)`.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. Can you see what I am doing wrong in my script: [Google App example script](https://script.google.com/a/webstep.no/d/1BmBY9_xcXFWxa5wNr95Vd8USIbGipK8eEoi3T9NhOzBjdrFZc3IoTcSd/edit) console.log does not log anything to my chrome javascript console, only **NaN**. I have to add () when calling ajaxError otherwise the function is not run at all. And I guess since I am not passing in parameters.. they are undefined.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the published version of this script? I'd like to take a look at that.

Comment: yes [published link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxbICIDKVoRs0Q6Zhl-Foc9DuoC2mxYh5MlSz7GsB9leWdCQ6M/exec)